# Hamilton Circuit

Tags: graphs, traveling-salesman, hamiltonian-circuit

The Dirac's theorem states that:
"For a Graph G with N vertices, if the degree of each vertex is atleast N/2 then, the Graph has a Hamilton Circuit."
Can the same be said if a graph has a Hamilton Circuit then the degree of each vertex is atleast N/2 ?

Answer (score 3):

No. A graph with only the edges of a polygon has an Hamilton circle, but the degree of each vertex is 2.

Comment: Such a graph is usually called a *cycle* or *circuit*.

Comment: I think that's the condition for an Euler Circuit to exist. @shuki